# Where can I find code of zkEVM (from zkSync)?

Tags: zksnark, zksync

from https://zksync.io/zkevm/#what-is-zkevm-and-why-is-this-a-big-deal

> zkEVM is a virtual machine that executes smart contracts in a way that is compatible with zero-knowledge proof computation.

where can I find the code of zkEVM?

Comment: Shouldn't you ask this question from zkSync developers?

Comment: https://zksync.io/contact.html Feel free to reopen this question when you get the answer. Thanks.